# QML NumberAnimation: setRunning() cannot be used on non-root animation nodes

Tags: qt, popup, qml

My code is here:

`MyPopup.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Popup {
  id: popup
  width: 250
  height: 250
  closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
  y: -300

  background: Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: '#3f3f3f'
    opacity: 15
    Text {
      text: 'HELLO WORLD!'
      color: 'white'
      font.pointSize: 20
      anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Button {
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
      text: 'Close Popup'
      onClicked: popup.close()
    }
  }

  enter: Transition {
    NumberAnimation {
      target: parent
      property: 'y'
      to: (Screen.height / 2) - (height / 2)
      duration: 400
      running: true
    }
  }

  exit: Transition {
    NumberAnimation {
      target: parent
      property: 'y'
      to: -((Screen.height / 2) - (height / 2))
      duration: 400
      running: true
    }
  }
}
```

I put a button into `main.qml`. When I click that button, `popup.open()` is running. I put a button into `MyPopup.qml`, when I click that button, `popup.close()` is running. When I clik the buttons, my app is freezing and closing.

I get this warnings:
`qrc:/MyPopup.qml:31:5: QML NumberAnimation: setRunning() cannot be used on non-root animation nodes.`
`qrc:/MyPopup.qml:41:5: QML NumberAnimation: setRunning() cannot be used on non-root animation nodes.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#enter-prop), two examples are given and none of them have `running` property instantiated. Example of `enter` property:

```
Popup {
    enter: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0.0; to: 1.0 }
    }
}
```

And for `exit` property:

```
Popup {
    exit: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 1.0; to: 0.0 }
    }
}
```

I tried your code without `running: true` line and it worked. So when `popup.open()` or `popup.exit()` are called, the transitions just run.